# Indesign vs illustrator colour profiles

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, color-profile, color-reproduction

Currently running Adobe Suite CC 2017.

Im currently working on some branding material which requires work to be done in Illustrator and indesign.

However when creating the artwork I'm using the CMYK values in both but I keep getting different colours.

Both programs have the same colour settings which has been setup to our print suppliers. Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using Adobe Bridge to synchronise the colour settings of all your Adobe applications?

Comment: no I haven't. I've never used bridge tbh

Comment: It's worth giving it a go. It takes the headache out of the task! Here's the link on how to http://help.adobe.com/en_US/creativesuite/cs/using/WS37C6D4EA-9407-4954-9A03-92735E070188.html#WSA0A53A1F-BF46-4624-82C6-340A70EFB8C4

Comment: both programs (indesign and illustrator) hold the correct CMYK values how ever both programs hold different HEX codes? and both show two different shades of colour.

Comment: That might have something to do with the preview in InDesign - also make sure you have colour proofing switched on in both apps.

Comment: Also, check this out - the problem seems to be to do with the preview https://forums.adobe.com/thread/867243